# How do I access a value of a Blob?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a `Blob` object.  When I `console.log` it, the result is:

```
Blob {
  [Symbol(type)]: 'image/jpeg',
  [Symbol(buffer)]: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff e1 01 0e 45 78 69 66 00 00 4d 4d 00 2a 00 00 00 08 00 08 01 06 00 03 00 00 00 01 00 02 ... 956836 more bytes>
}
```

How do I access that buffer?

Comment: Also, do any of the methods [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) help?

Comment: A `Blob` in node.js? Are you using some library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use stream, arrayBuffer or text.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob#Methods

Example

```
blob.text().then(x => console.log(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use from the following options

1. Using FileReader

   var blobReader = new FileReader();

   blobReader.onload = function() {
       alert(blobReader.result);
   }

   blobReader.readAsText(blob);

   (OR)

   const blobText = await new Response(blob).text();

Comment: There is no `FileReader` in node.js?

Comment: oh.. we were using similar to this in our frontend react app, so thought it would help.